While trying to get a non-English character from the SSL certificate's subject, it returns an encoded value
In nginx, while trying to get a non-English character from the client certificate's subject, it returns an encoded value.
I need the actual value in nginx so that I can handle my case.
For example, if in subject I have a value as TÉST and trying to retrieve the value, it is getting returned as T\C3\A9ST.
Expecting a solution to handle the case in nginx itself without any other third party integration with nginx.

What exactly does “get the value in nginx” mean? How are you “getting” it where?

To say clearly, I am adding a value to the certificate subject to validate that in nginx if this certificate comes in the request. But this value is not constant. It changes.
So if this value contains a non-english character, it is getting escaped as mentioned above. But I need the actual value in nginx instead of encoded value for verification purposes.

And I ask again: where exactly are you confirming that how? I’m not doubting what you’re claiming, but to fully understand what exactly you’re doing and how exactly one might help in that case requires that you tell us a little more. nginx isn’t a programming language or anything where it might be more self evident how exactly some value is “gotten”.

I'm adding a custom value to the subject field of a client certificate, which will be issued to the client. When the client makes a request, this value will be passed as a parameter, and I need to verify that it matches the value embedded in the certificate.
To achieve this, I'm using $ssl_client_s_dn to extract the subject from the client certificate. However, when the subject contains non-English characters, they are returned in the format, as described in my earlier question.

Please see my answer here
That is a long Post, but essentially, when Nginx reads the Cert Subject DN and assigns the value to $ssl_client_s_dn, if "Non-English" characters are present (Ascii > 127, or other formats allowed in Cert Distinguished Name), then it will be read from the Client Cert presented to Nginx as such.
While there are details of your implementation that are missing, at least you mention that Nginx should validate correct Subject DN before further processing (passing request to Upstream, or internally when App && Nginx are on same server).
One should have a short list of accepted Subject DN's in that case, and these can be Mapped. Note that there aren't any regex keys in the map... if this becomes necessary, do the work to reduce numerous regex keys into few but readable instances.
Here is sample code to validate Cert Subject DN based on the Example given, and then the implementation of a 403 for unwanted Client Certs.
#in http {} block
map $ssl_client_s_dn $reject_client_cert {
    "T\C3\89ST" 0; #allow "TÉST"
    "R\C3\A4ksm\C3\B6rg\C3\A5s" 0;  #allow "Räksmörgås"
    default 1; #else reject
}

#in server {} block before location {} blocks for better reading:
if ($reject_client_cert) {
    #set $append_log 'loc=reject s_dn=$ssl_client_s_dn'; custom logging could to be set up to provide useful stats on rejects

    return 403; #you may provide a custom error code/page if desired 
}

Note: I dislike IF statements in Nginx configs, but for this use-case it is well suited.

Thankyou for your answer. But the value TÉST is not a constant value. It may vary based on the client.
